# A java method to read numbers into array and return in to main function. but my code returns errors. can someone look into this?

Tags: java, arrays

A java method to read numbers into array and return in to main function. but my code returns errors. can someone look into this?

```
package usefulfunctions;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class readingarray {

int reading()
{
    int array[] = null;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count;
        System.out.println("number of elements to enter");
        count=inp.nextInt();

        for(int k=0;k<count;k++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter numbers into array");
            array[k]=inp.nextInt();
        }

    return array[];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    readingarray ob = new readingarray();
    int arr[]=ob.reading();



}

}
```

in the above code, the method `reading()` should read data and return the array to the main method.

Comment: remove the brackets `[]` when returning the array. `return array[];` -> `return array;`

Comment: So it returns errors, but you don't think knowing the error message could be useful in identifying the problem? Why?

Comment: Please include the text of your compiler error messages in your question.

Comment: The return type on your method should be int[]. Also you never instantiated your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are more than one mistake:

1. `int array[] = null;` must be `int[] array=null;`
2. `array` variable never initialized, so at `array[k]=inp.nextInt();` there will be NPE

   - add before `for` statement `array = new int[count];`
3. as mentioned by @Lino above:  `return array[];` must be  `return array;`